# Installing ML 10.8 Using Internet Recovery freezes during install process

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, install

I changed my Mac HDD because the other one was corrupted. But when I do the Internet Recovery install, the bar on OS X Mountain Lion Install Page (Downloading Additional Components) goes all the way to the end when it says remaining 0 seconds and then the minutes go up again like 43 min remaining but the progress bar is stuck at the end of the bar, like it is in a download loop.

Comment: How long have you waited? Oftentimes the best solution is to just wait out the hang. I'd recommend letting the install run overnight and seeing if it's better in the morning.

Comment: Probably like 8 hours man.

Comment: Oh. Wow. Never mind, then!

Comment: What bothers me the most is when the bar goes to the end why does the minutes go up?

Comment: [This comic](http://xkcd.com/612/) says it best. It also applies to OS X.

Comment: lol that was funny

Comment: Do you have another Mac on hand that you could use for making a bootable drive, and do you have any objections to getting Yosemite?

Comment: I dont have another mac and i could try anything in order so i can fix this.

Comment: Okay... got any other computers on hand, regardless of OS?

Comment: I got an windows that I'm writing from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This thread](https://superuser.com/questions/383235/create-a-bootable-usb-drive-from-a-dmg-file-on-windows) looks like it has instructions on how to make a bootable OS X drive from Windows. If you have an 8GB USB drive that you're willing to part with, you can do this and then use the bootable drive to install OS X on your new hard drive.

Comment: So than, my Mac will try to install it from the USB?

Comment: Yeah. Hold down Option while turning the Mac on, and it'll open a list of drives to boot from. Select the newly-made bootable USB drive, and you'll open something that looks very much like Internet Recovery except with OS X already fully downloaded.

Comment: Can i do that using a DISK aswell?

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't, as long as the disk has 8GB. (I can tell you from experience that it also works on SD cards, for that matter.)

Comment: Really? I have only one SD card 16GB. The same process for everything?

Comment: That could support a bootable OS X drive just fine, but it'd be a shame to waste that extra space. I'd recommend partitioning it into two 8GB drives, one for general storage and one to be the bootable drive.

Comment: And do i have to format the SD Card BEfore?

Comment: I can't vouch for the process on Windows, but on a Mac, the drive has to be formatted with a GUID Partition Table.

Comment: Actually, if you wanted to do this by the Apple-sanctioned method, you could set up an OS X virtual machine on your PC and then follow [these instructions](http://www.macworld.com/article/2367748/how-to-make-a-bootable-os-x-10-10-yosemite-install-drive.html).

Comment: There's nothing 'apple-sanctioned' about virtualising OS X on a PC.

Comment: @Tetsujin I know. I was referring to the process of making a bootable OS X drive, not the steps you have to take to be able to meet the system requirements first.